# Is it possible to make a terminal frame to be appeared on the bottom, not on the top?

Tags: vimrc, terminal

I'm using `:term bash` to show a terminal buffer as it is specified in `:h terminal-use`. But the problem is that it is appeared on the top of the currently active vim buffer.

Is there a `vimrc` configuration to make it be appeared on the bottom instead?

Comment: I think :term ++bottom, but check the help page

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Just tried and got `E181: Invalid attribute: bottom`

Comment: Eh, oh well. Really, `:help :term` lists attributes. Could be bot

Comment: try this: `:bot :term`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any command opening a split in Vim is influenced by `splitbelow` (horizontal) and `splitright` (vertical) options. So terminal opens on top, because you have `set nosplitbelow` (this is the default setting).

So you can either change a global setting, or use an additional "modifier" command as needed. These modifiers are `aboveleft`, `belowright`, `topleft` and `botright`. You probably need one of `:below term`or `:bot term`.